# Automate creating Folder on Layer Panel on QGIS using python?

Tags: qgis, python

How can I automate creating multiple Folder with sets of its own Folder Namr on a Layer Panel on QGIS using python?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with how Layer Panel in QGIS works, but in Python you just do the following:

```
import os
directory = os.path.dirname('E://dirName') 
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)
```

It's well described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/how-can-i-create-a-directory-if-it-does-not-exist